# QGIS - merge overlapping polygons based on attributes while retaining attributes of one of them

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, dissolve

This question seems simple, but I cannot figure it out. The problem is - I have a layer of polygons with animal species habitats. Different species can occupy overlapping or even THE SAME area, but polygons for a single species cannot overlap.

I have two types of errors in the layer that I want to remove:

1. partially overlapping polygons for the same species must be merged into one
2. 100% overlapping features of the same species must be deleted, while 100% overlapping features of another species must be retained (no "delete duplicated geometries")

`dissolve` and `v.dissolve` don't produce what I want. I tried more elaborated solutions, like splitting layer by species and working on individual species. While I can delete duplicates I cannot find a way to merge only overlapping polygons without manual editing.

Comment: How did your dissolves fail?  Are you trying to preserve other attributes besides species?  If you dissolve on a species attribute alone that should work if that is all you care about.  You may not want multi-part polygons but there should be a setting to avoid that (e.g. in the GDAL dissolve tool check the "Produce one feature for each geometry...." box), or you could run the multipart to singlepart tool afterwards.